# Special character as delimiter Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have an input file like this. I have to create hive external table on top of this hdfs file. I tried with \u00A1 and \u001 as the delimiter but it's not working.

Kindly suggest.

```
1¡1407¡231819¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡I¡1¡0¡10¡Long NAME 1448607¡0¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡1448607¡D¡D

8¡90688¡225895¡0.0050000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡0.00000000¡383.02000000¡383.02000000¡T¡1¡0¡10¡SHORT NAME
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42751359/6336479

Comment: What would be octal or hexadecimal value in my case?

Comment: http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/AsciiChart.jsp ----- http://www.ascii-code.net ------ http://ascii.cl/conversion.htm ----- http://calc.50x.eu

Comment: @Vinitkumar It is Hex A1 (\u00A1).

With the link @DuduMarkovitz shared it might work. If some columns are showing `null`, then you got to extract few lines from hdfs files into a textfile, open with notepad++ or something to figure out exact delimiters (In N++ there is an encoding option in the menu bar, which you might to fiddle with).